# Angular: action directive for eye gaze steering, wrap ng-click in another directive

Tags: angularjs

For a web app, which can be controlled either by mouse or by eye movements, I need a special directive for buttons. Let's call it `ng-action`. My question is just about: how to call its argument within an angular directive? So it's not relevant, what logic there is behind eye gaze control, but maybe: **how to wrap ng-click in another directive so we have more control about when the action is called?**

`<button ng-action="activateField(1,2)">Activate...</button>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems I have found the answer. It was easier then I thought.

`scope.$eval(atts.ngAction)` does it.